# TypeError: is not a function when calling class method

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

Apologies if this is a really basic question, but I've been struggling to find an answer.

I am trying to call a method/function inside a class client side but when I try to call it, I get `TypeError testFunction is not a function`

The entry point is client.ts, which (to keep it simple for now) has a single export:

```
export * from "./Test"
```

Test.ts has a class and function:

```
export class TestClass {

    public testFunction() {

        // do stuff

    }

}
```

My webpack.config.js is as follows:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

var argv = require('yargs').argv;

var debug = argv.debug !== undefined;

var config = [
    {
        entry: {
            client: [
                __dirname + '/src/scripts/client.ts'
            ]
        },
        mode: debug ? 'development' : 'production',
        output: {
            path: __dirname + '/dist/web/scripts',
            filename: '[name].js',
            libraryTarget: 'umd',
            library: 'webpack',
            publicPath: '/scripts/'
        },
        externals: {},
        devtool: 'source-map',
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
            alias: {}
        },
        target: 'web',
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: [/lib/, /dist/],
                loader: "ts-loader",
                options: {
                    configFile: "tsconfig-client.json"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: 'public/fonts/[name].[ext]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                ]
            }
            ]
        },
        performance: {
            maxEntrypointSize: 400000,
            maxAssetSize: 400000,
            assetFilter: function (assetFilename) {
                return assetFilename.endsWith('.js');
            }
        }
    }
];

module.exports = config;
```

I am them embedding this in the html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Bookings</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="/scripts/client.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        webpack.TestClass.testFunction();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any pointers on what I am doing wrong would be great. If I browse the generated client.js I can see the class and method, so I am at a loss!

```
/*!*****************************!*\
  !*** ./src/scripts/Test.ts ***!
  \*****************************/
/*! namespace exports */
/*! export TestClass [provided] [no usage info] [missing usage info prevents renaming] */
/*! other exports [not provided] [no usage info] */
/*! runtime requirements: __webpack_require__.r, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__.d, __webpack_require__.* */
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
/* harmony export */   "TestClass": () => /* binding */ TestClass
/* harmony export */ });
var TestClass = /** @class */ (function () {
    function TestClass() {
    }
    TestClass.prototype.testFunction = function () {
        // do stuff
    };
    return TestClass;
}());
```

Comment: `TestClass`, the class (actualy a function when transpiled, as you can see in your bottom snippet), does not have any property called `testFunction`. It is *instances* of the class that have this function property. (Via `TestClass.prototype`.)

Comment: Ah yes, how did I not spot that. Sorry for the silly question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to call a non-static method directly from `TestClass` instead of creating a new *instance* of `TestClass` first.

You need to either call the `testFunction` method on a new instance of `TestClass` or declare the `testFunction` method as a `static` method.

Comment: Yep, that works. Not sure how I missed that bit, I've been using classes elsewhere for a while!